# Any experiment showing the “communication” between entangled particles is superluminal but not simultaneous OR simultaneous?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

Do the numerous experiments that demonstrate a violation of Bell’s inequality also provide any data that the “communication” (I’m using that word for simplicity) between the entangled particles is superluminal but not simultaneous OR that such “communication” is indeed simultaneous?

I’ve looked at the papers of several of these experiments (e.g., Aspect et al. 1982, Tittel et al. 1998, Salart et al. 2008, Handsteiner et al. 2017, Rosenfeld et al. 2017), and as best as I can tell (I’m not a physicist), they don’t present data that address this question (i.e., superluminal but not simultaneous versus simultaneous).  But I would like a second opinion because I’m not an expert. I just enjoy reading and learning about this.  I’m asking what—-if anything—-these (or other?) experiments tell us as relates to my question, not what QM would tell us.

Answer (score 2):

No. The experiments do not show superluminal communication. When Alice performs her experiment on particle A, there is no observation or experiment which Bob can perform which will tell him anything about Alice's experiment, or even whether Alice has performed an experiment. Only later, when Alice and Bob get together and compare their results, do they find a correlation which violates Bell's inequality. All this tells them is that there is no classical explanation for the correlation they observe.

This can be understood because the quantum state describes an observer's knowledge of the particle, not the physical state of the particle (as illustrated in Schrodinger's cat and Wigner's friend). If Alice measures particle A, she acquires knowledge of particle B, causing Alice's wave function for particle B to collapse. This has no *physical* impact on particle B. Bob, who measures particle B, cannot detect Alice's result. Alice's wave function for particle B collapsed, but Bob's did not.

There are differences between quantum probability and classical probability, but the principle is the same. Quantum probability amplitudes (otherwise known as wave functions) allow us to calculate probabilities, where probability is an estimation of likelihood by an observer, not a description of physical reality.